# Get Highest Value By Hour in MongoDB for given Date Range?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following document structure in MongoDB :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c1b7451b1829b69963029ea"),
    "duration" : 92,
    "accountId" : ObjectId("9aafe7b01cf4560c9bb5d68"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-12-20T10:52:01.560Z"),
    "__v" : 0,
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c1b7451b1829b69963029ea"),
    "duration" : 192,
    "accountId" : ObjectId("9aafe7b01cf4560c9bb5d68"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-12-20T11:52:01.560Z"),
    "__v" : 0,
}
```

Now I want to get the highest sum of duration for the day with corresponding hour. Technically, something like this :

```
{
    "readableDate" : "2018-12-20",
    "hour" : 11,
    "total" : 192
}
```

Where total is the hourly total which is HIGHEST for that particular day.

The query which I have tried is as follows :

```
db.getCollection('operational_details').aggregate(


            {"$match": {"accountId": ObjectId("9aafe7b01cf4560c9bb5d68"),
                            "createdAt": {"$gte": ISODate("2019-06-01T10:30:29.725Z"),
                                          "$lte": ISODate("2019-06-04T10:30:29.725Z")},
                            }},
     { "$project": {
          "date": {"$dateToString": {"format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$createdAt"}}, 
          "hour": {"$hour":"$createdAt"},
         "total":{"$sum": "$duration"} }
     },
     { "$group":{ 
           "_id": { "hour":"$hour","date":"$date"},
           "max": {"$max": "$total"}
       }})
```

Hope I am clear with my example. TIA

Comment: please approve my answer if you like my efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below

working playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Gxj3rWhPxVh)

//Array

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5cf4f20243f560e1e0a77014"),
    "duration": 92,
    "accountId": ObjectId("6ef4f20243f560e1e0a77015"),
    "createdAt": ISODate("2018-12-20T10:52:10.320Z")
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5cf4f21843f560e1e0a7701a"),
    "duration": 192,
    "accountId": ObjectId("6ef4f20243f560e1e0a77015"),
    "createdAt": ISODate("2018-12-20T11:52:11.123Z")
  }
]
```

//Script

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "accountId": {
        $eq: ObjectId("6ef4f20243f560e1e0a77015")
      },
      "createdAt": {
        $gte: ISODate("2018-12-19T10:30:00.000Z"),
        $lte: ISODate("2018-12-21T10:30:00.000Z")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "date": {
        "$dateToString": {
          "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
          "date": "$createdAt"
        }
      },
      "hour": {
        "$hour": "$createdAt"
      },
      "duration": "$duration"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "hour": "$hour",
        "date": "$date"
      },
      "total": {
        "$sum": "$duration"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "readableDate": "$_id.date",
      "hour": "$_id.hour",
      "total": "$total"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "total": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 1
  }
])
```

//Result

```
[
  {
    "hour": 11,
    "readableDate": "2018-12-20",
    "total": 192
  }
]
```

Comment: I tried the same but I am getting answer in the following format : 


```
{
    "_id" : {
        "hour" : 1,
        "date" : "2019-06-02"
    },
    "readableDate" : "2019-06-02",
    "hour" : 1,
    "total" : 934
}

{
    "_id" : {
        "hour" : 10,
        "date" : "2019-06-03"
    },
    "readableDate" : "2019-06-03",
    "hour" : 10,
    "total" : 98
},
{
    "_id" : {
        "hour" : 11,
        "date" : "2019-06-02"
    },
    "readableDate" : "2019-06-02",
    "hour" : 11,
    "total" : 282
}
``` 
Unlike of what I want in the O/P

Comment: Thanks for the effort Ratan but your updated query return null now :(

Comment: Okay I apologize if I am not clear with the kind of O/P I want. I want sum of highest duration of the day along with the hour. Please see the question once again. And NOT the multiple hourly value for same day.

Comment: I am thankful for your time Ratan but I need max value for the day let's say from 10-11 AM total of duration is 115 and from 12-13PM total duration comes out to be 119 for let's say date 01-06-2019. In that case I want output to be 
 {
    "hour": 13,
    "readableDate": "2019-06-01",
    "total": 119
  }

And not any other value for that particular day.

Comment: I have updated my answer. please approve my answer and upvote